# Locking scheme a hack

Tags: c++, synchronization

How's this look:

```
class HugeHack
{
    HugeHack() : m_flag( false ) { }

    void Logout( )
    {
        boost::lock_guard< boost::mutex > lock( m_lock );
        m_flag = true;

        // do stuff that in a perfect world would be atomic with library call and onLogout

        // call a library function that waits for a thread to finish, that thread calls my onLogout() function before it dies

        m_flag = false;
    }


    void onLogout()
    {
        boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > l( m_lock, boost::defer_lock_t );
        if( ! m_flag )
            l.lock();

        // do stuff

    }



    boost::mutex m_lock;
    bool m_flag;
};
```

The flag is true ONLY while Logout is running, Logout legitimately waits for a thread to die that calls onLogout, so unless someone else can call onLogout... (can't be totally sure not my library I'm using - QuickFix)

I'm not sure I'm using the unique lock correctly there, if not, the goal is only to conditionally lock the lock (while maintaining scoped locking semantics).

Comment: I don't think I see a question in here.  It "looks" fine, but only with respect to the fact that you've not indicated what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: doesn't boost's lock have try_lock or so, because it seems to me that's what you're after.. don't think m_Flag is needed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you read m_flag without locking the mutex, you might see m_flag be false even if in reality it is true, and Logout is in the middle of operation. Locking the mutex issues a memory fence, which is essential to ensure proper memory visibility. And BTW stijn is right - if this is all you are after, you can ditch m_flag and use try_lock instead, like this:

```
boost::mutex::scoped_try_lock l( m_lock );
if ( l )
    // lock succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is release the lock in `Logout` at the point you are waiting for the thread to terminate (and call `onLogout`). So do that instead, then unconditionally take the lock in `onLogout`.